# Alternative to the Hotel Gellért

Tags: hungary, budapest

Our family will be in Budapest in a couple days and were hoping to stay at the Hotel Gellért, but understand that it's closed for repairs. Is there a similar historic hotel close to the baths?

Comment: The Continental is not as famous, but it's about as old (1910), used to host baths and still has a spa.  https://continentalhotelbudapest.com/

Comment: Also, did you really mean bordel as in house of prostitution? I don't think Gellert was ever one.

Comment: @lambshaanxy The bath area in Gellert could be rented for prostitute spiked sex partys at least as recently as 10 years ago.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I need a source. You know, for science.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I meant hotel. Thanks for the tip about  the continental.

Comment: @MastaBaba There was this story from 10 years ago: https://www.spiegel.de/international/business/ergo-report-reveals-details-of-budapest-bathhouse-sex-party-scandal-a-850168.html